# AngularJS forEach loop overwriting previous array elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm having such a weird issue whereby each iteration of the one of the `angular.forEach` loops seen below is overwriting the previously pushed elements with its value.

I know this has something to do with the scope of the object being pushed but I can't figure out where my 'leak' is. The `completedForm` is whats being pushed onto the array `completedForms`.

```
    function auditToObservations(audit){
  var completedForms = [];
  var observations;
  // get form with same id as audit
  var form = FormService.getFormForUserByIds(userService.getAuditorId(), audit.formId);
  if(form){
    if(form.has_subforms){
      observations = audit.payload.observations[0];
    }
    else{
      observations = audit.payload.observations;
    }
    var compNum = 0;
    angular.forEach(observations, function(observation, key){
      if(key != 'date' && key != 'ward' || !form.has_subforms){
        angular.forEach(form.forms, function(subform, index){
          var completedForm = {};
          if(!form.has_subforms || subform.sub_observation_model.split('.')[2].toLowerCase() === key){
            completedForm = {
              form_title: subform.display_title,
              completion_no: ++compNum,
              observation_model: subform.observation_model,
              form_data: []
            };

            angular.forEach(subform.fields, function(field){
              field.value = observation[field.backend_name];
              completedForm.form_data.push(field);
            });
            if(form.has_subforms){
                completedForm.id = index.toString();
                completedForms[index] = completedForm;
            }
            else{
                completedForm.id = key.toString();
                completedForms[key] = completedForm;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return completedForms;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Is this method async: getFormForUserByIds?

Comment: Nope! Its using LocalStorage totally synchronously.

Comment: Is there a certain reason you use angular.forEach and not the ES6 .map() function?

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you provided input, expected output, and actual output.